# How can I make a function have library-internal linkage?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, linker, ld

For example, if I have two files `foo.c` and `bar.o`, and `foo.c` contains a function `foo()` that references a function `bar()` in `bar.o`:

```
int foo(int x) { x = bar(x); /* ... */ }
```

How can I compile a static or dynamic library that exposes `foo()`, but does not expose `bar()`? In other words, I want `bar()` to be linked only inside the library.

Comment: It depends on how bar is compiled... If you build with -fvisibility=hidden you don't need to do anything but link it in.

Comment: I'm confused. How is `bar` exposed? If the library user code only `#includes` `foo.h`, it will only be able to call the functions declared there. The functions that call `bar()` should be defined in `foo.c`, so as long as `foo.h` doesn't include `bar.h`, everything should be fine. What am I missing?

Comment: @AustinMullins: The problem is at the linker level. The linker doesn't look at `.h` files. It looks directly at binaries.

Comment: Right. That's what I'm saying. How is `bar` exposed to user code?

Comment: @AustinMullins: It is in the library. If you have a non-static `bar` in your code and you link with my library, there will be a linker conflict.

Comment: for a dynamic library, you could try to use the `ld` option `-- exclude-symbols symbol,symbol,...` (just saw it in the man pages, I haven't tried it)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With standard C you can only either export the function or not, there is no “export only to these files” option. So basically you would have to move `bar()` to `foo.c` and declare it as `static`. If you wish to keep the file separate, an ugly hack would be to `#include` it from `foo.c` (and not compile `bar.o`)…

With tools outside the scope of standard C you can remove the public export from the library at or after linking. Some linker solutions are shown below, and with GCC and clang (in cases where you can modify the code) you can hide a function by prefixing it with the non-standard attribute: `__attribute__ ((visibility ("hidden")))` – the compilation-unit-wide equivalent of this would be the option `-fvisibility=hidden` when compiling, e.g., `bar.c`.

### C workaround

If you can edit the C code freely, a workaround in standard C would be to make `bar()` `static` within `bar.c` and deliver a function pointer to it for use in `foo()` through some means, e.g., export a pointer to a `struct` containing the function pointer (and any other “private” data), and do not expose the details of the `struct` outside of a private header used only by your library.

For example:

In `bar.h` (private, do not share with the library's user):

```
struct bar_private_struct { int (*bar)(int); };
extern struct bar_private_struct *bar_functions;
```

In `bar.c`:

```
#include "bar.h"
static int bar (int x) { /* … */ return x; }
static struct bar_private_struct functions = { bar };
struct bar_private_struct *bar_functions = &functions;
```

In `foo.c`:

```
#include "bar.h"
int foo (int x) { x = bar_functions->bar(x); /* … */ }
```

In this solution there will be an exported pointer called `bar_functions`, but no details about the data/functions pointed to are revealed through this export. Without access to `bar.h` the user of the library would have to reverse engineer the contents to call the “private” functions correctly. In case of multiple “private” functions this approach can also condense them to a single exported pointer, removing clutter from the list of exports.

### Linker solutions

Exploring specific linkers, I found a way to exclude specific symbols from a dynamic library:

With GNU `ld`, create a version script, such as `libfoobar.version`:

```
FOOBAR {
    global: *;
    local: bar;
};
```

Invocation through `gcc`:

```
gcc -shared -o libfoobar.so foo.o bar.o -Wl,-version-script=libfoobar.version
```

With the `clang` `ld` (on OS X) create a list of unexported symbols, such as `unexported` (one symbol per line):

```
_bar
```

Invocation through `clang`:

```
clang -shared -o libfoobar.dylib foo.o bar.o -Wl,-unexported_symbols_list,unexported
```

In both cases the function `bar` is hidden and externally uncallable but `foo` remains operational (and calls `bar` internally), even though both had the same external visibility in their respective source (and object) files.

Test code, `foo.c`:

```
int bar(int x);
int foo (int x) { return bar(x) * 3; }
```

`bar.c`:

```
int bar (int x) { return x * 2; }
```

`main.c` (link against the library before removing the export for `bar`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int foo(int x);
int bar(int x);
int main () {
    (void) printf("foo(2) = %d\n", foo(2));
    (void) printf("bar(2) = %d\n", bar(2));
    return 0;
}
```

Test case:

```
# before unexporting bar:
$ nm -gU libfoobar.dylib
0000000000000f70 T _bar
0000000000000f50 T _foo
$ ./main
foo(2) = 12
bar(2) = 4

# after unexporting bar:
$ nm -gU libfoobar.dylib
0000000000000f50 T _foo
$ ./main
foo(2) = 12
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _bar
```

Comment: The problem is `bar.o` might not be compiled from C, or may be compiled from C but with different options. In either case, your workaround doesn't work.

Comment: What are the "specific tools"?

Comment: That's a nice obfuscation but what does prevent a module outside the library to call `bar_functions->bar(x)` the same way `foo.c` module does it? `bar_functions` object will still have external linkage.

Comment: I don't have a `bar.c`, I have a `bar.o`. Your approach still exposes `bar_functions`, which is not any different from exposing `bar`.

Comment: @ouah If `bar.h` is not available to the user, they would have to reverse engineer the contents of `bar_functions`. Of course they can do that, but I would argue that similarly they could reverse engineer the contents of the library itself and create their own pointer to `bar()`…

Comment: @Matt Exporting a pointer to a `struct` of unknown composition is definitely different from exporting a function `bar`, especially in terms of what it signals to the user of the library. But if you only have `bar.o`, which you can not edit the source of, then clearly you can no longer control whether `bar` is exported or not… Your only choice seems to be some means outside of C, i.e., some linker tool.

Comment: @Arkku: The problem is not that I don't want people calling it, the problem is I don't want the symbol exposed, and your method just changes what the symbol points to (data rather than instructions).

Comment: Since tags indicate that the GNU toolchain is in use, the desired result can be obtained by declaring function bar with `__attribute__ ((__visibility__ ("hidden")))`.  This produces exactly the result requested, even with `bar()` compiled separately, for targets that support it (which include ELF).  Although support for this kind of linkage is standard in ELF, support for declaring it in C is a GCC extension.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I actually edited my answer to include a mention of the attribute just minutes before your comment, but I'm not sure if it's possible to somehow specify this attribute for the function `bar` if you only have `bar.o` and not its source code (which might be non-C, interpreting the OP's question strictly). So can you somehow apply the attribute externally (e.g., in a header you can create)?

Comment: @Arkku, to the best of my knowledge, that attribute needs to be associated with `bar()`s declaration during that function's own compilation for it to be effective.  It affects details of the object file.  It might be possible to modify the existing object file to change the symbol's visibility, but that's out of my depth.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Do you know if there is a way to do this in a way that's portable across Linux, OS X, and Cygwin?

Comment: @Matt, I do not know.  The `__attribute__` approach is the best idea I have if you're committed to GCC, but I am uncertain whether it is effective on OS X or Cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

Functions can only have internal or external linkage.

If you want to use different modules, your functions need to have external linkage so they can be called from one translation unit to the other.

You can use an external function pointer to a static function but of course this will still allow the other modules to call the function through the function pointer.

Comment: I don't "want" to use different modules. I just have to compile `bar.o` in a completely different way. And then link it as if it were defined as a static function in `foo.c`.